# Inline SVG Height / Viewbox not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg, height, inline

I am working with a large SVG container and while it looks fine everywhere else and scales nicely for mobile, Internet Explorer does not seem to read the height of the SVG.

```
<svg id="section-one-svg-container" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" version="1.1" viewBox="0 3022.75 940 6986">
</svg>
```

As you can tell there, I have removed the width and height values to allow for the SVG to scale cleanly. The CSS is pretty vague:

```
svg {width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

However, in IE, 9+ the SVG element is showing with a height of ~100px despite there being content in there that should stretch it to its full height.  Any recommendations on how to have IE see the full height of the SVG container?

Comment: At the back of my head, I seem to remember IE has some problems with preserveAspectRatio - try removing and seeing what happens (semi-magical suggestion)